# create bounding box in drupal openlayers module

Tags: drupal, openlayers

Is there a feature in the Drupal Open Layers module to paint a bounding box simply on node edit on the map, instead feeding a data view from text input for the bounds?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the OpenLayers module does this out of the box.

You'll probably need to use modules like:
http://drupal.org/project/views_geojson
http://drupal.org/project/geofield

Either way, probably best to ask the question here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Not sure what you mean by editing the node on the map.  Your question could use some additional clarification.